# What proportion of the quarter circle is shaded?

Tags: geometry, area

[image]

Interesting yet challenging quiz I found on a website. My answer is a $\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2}}$.

After I assumed the semicircle has radius $r\sin{45}$, where $r$ is the radius of the quarter circular part.

Any objections or comment?

Answer (score 1):

Your result is not correct. Let $R$ be the radius of the quarter circle and $r$ be the radius of the half-circle. Then, by Pythagoras theorem applied to $\triangle OO'C$,
$$R^2=r^2+d^2$$
where $d=\sqrt{2}r$ is the distance of the two centers $O$ and $O'$ (note that $\angle O'OH=45^{\circ}$).

Can you take it from here?

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me. Of course a good picture is necessary to draw. The picture in the post is not very clear on what the actual geometrical constraints are.

Comment: Sorry my omission, the semicircle is tangent to the quarter circle. I can take it from here which gives 2/3 as the probable answer, no solution was given though. Thanks.

Comment: @MattiP. Now we have a better picture.

Comment: Solution accepted, Robert Z , Matti, for a great discussion.

Comment: @WaitaraMburu If you want to accept an answer please take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be the radius of the outer circle and  $M=(r,r)$ be the center of the brown semidisc. Then $|OM|=\sqrt{2} r$ and therefore $R^2=3r^2$. The ratio of the areas then comes to ${2\over3}$.

Comment: accepted as a quicker version, Christian!